# How to get variable (const?) value in other component in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, web3js

I starting using React. I have a main file (App.js) where all logic comes and in that file, I have added routes (, , ) which loading different page by URL from other files (only content).

In App.js constructor I added the web3 package and write that in a variable (window, global variable) because that is only one way to get that variable in other components files. I don't want to use window variables, because every user can see that. I want to use const/var variables, but get that values in every single component files, but I don't want to load same web3 library (or to connect smart contracts in every single component file). How to do that?

Comment: You can use [Redux](https://redux.js.org/)

Comment: You can use context api

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean everything web3 has. On your component file

```
import React from 'react';
import Web3 from 'web3';

const ComponentA () => {
    // Do what ever you want with Web3 and react code here
};

export default ComponentA;
```

If you want the instance of web3 you created, maybe you could initialize web3 in its own file.

your own `web3_instance.js`

```
import Web3 from 'web3';

const web3Instance = new Web3();

export default web3Instance;
```

Then import it to any component.

```
import React from 'react';
import web3Instance from '../path/to/web3instance.js';

const ComponentA () => {
    // Do what ever you want with web3Instance and react code here
};

export default ComponentA;
```